# How can I check what value is assigned to what label while using sklearns' LabelEncoder()?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am transforming categorical data to numeric values for machine learning purposes.

To give an example, the buying price (= "buying" variable) of a car is categorized in: "vhigh, high, med, low".
To transform it into numeric values, I used:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
buying = le.fit_transform(list(data["buying"]))
```

Is there a way to check how exactly Python transformed each of those labels into numeric value since this is done randomly (e.g. vhigh = 0, high = 2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an extra column in your dataframe to map the values:

```
mapping_df = data[['buying']].copy() #Create an extra dataframe which will be used to address only the encoded values
mapping_df['buying_encoded'] = le.fit_transform(data['buying'].values) #Using values is faster than using list
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
data = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'buying':['Luffy','Nami','Luffy','Franky','Sanji','Zoro','Luffy']})
data['buying_encoded'] = le.fit_transform(data['buying'].values)
data = data.drop_duplicates('buying').set_index('index')
print(data)
```

Output:

```
       buying  buying_encoded
index                        
0       Luffy               1
1        Nami               2
3      Franky               0
4       Sanji               3
5        Zoro               4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the dictionary of what mapped to the categories as follow
starting from where @celius-stingher stopped,

```py
d1 = data.drop_duplicates('buying').drop('index', axis=1).set_index('buying')
print(d1)
```

Output:

```py
        buying_encoded
buying
Luffy                1
Nami                 2
Franky               0
Sanji                3
Zoro                 4
```

To transform this output to a dictionary,

```py
dict_map = d1.to_dict()
print(dict_map)
```

Output:

```
{'buying_encoded': {'Luffy': 1, 'Nami': 2, 'Franky': 0, 'Sanji': 3, 'Zoro': 4}}
```

So we can get the dictionary by taking the `buying_encoded` attribute from the returned `Dict`

```py
print(dict_map['buying_encoded'])
```

Output:

```
{'Luffy': 1, 'Nami': 2, 'Franky': 0, 'Sanji': 3, 'Zoro': 4}
```